# Sliding bottom panel through HTML, CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a menu that will slide from the bottom of the page on hover. I have already achieved the sliding effect, and my div already sits at the bottom of the screen, with the top 40px showing so you can hover on it to activate the sliding effect.
The problem is that the div is not "fixed" and it doesn't scroll with the page. I think a little JS would be the best solution

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="floatingmenu">
    <div id="listcontainer">
        <ul class="floatingcolumn">
            <li>Link 1</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="floatingcolumn">
            <li>Link 2</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="floatingcolumn">
            <li>Link 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#floatingmenu {
    width:100%;
    height:320px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-300px;
    z-index:99999;
    background:#000;
    -webkit-transition: all 700ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 700ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 700ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 700ms ease;
    transition: all 700ms ease;
}

#floatingmenu:hover {
    bottom:0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 700ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 700ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 700ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 700ms ease;
    transition: all 700ms ease;
}

#listcontainer {
    position:relative;
    width:900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#listcontainer ul {
    width:290px;
    float:left;
    color:FFF;
}
```

You can see it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fn6t7/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: please post a jsfiddle instead a link to your own page. this allows live coding / checking /testing

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the site's url with the fiddle now

Answer (score 2):

You should change your `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;` inside your `#floatingmenu` CSS class:

```
#floatingmenu {
   width:100%;
   height:320px;
   position:fixed;
   bottom:-300px;
   z-index:99999;
   background:#000;
   -webkit-transition: all 700ms ease;
   -moz-transition: all 700ms ease;
   -ms-transition: all 700ms ease;
   -o-transition: all 700ms ease;
   transition: all 700ms ease;
}
```

Comment: This does work with simple CSS and JS is not needed, position:fixed works fine, just tried it out with WebKit inspector.