# Sliding bottom panel through HTML, CSS, JS by clicking on card/tile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm beginner and trying to display details of a card/tile from the sliding bottom of the page over click action. I already found one of the template with my requirements and trying to customize. I found few code samples on how can I do sliding effect from the bottom. I was able to findout solution but it works with hover action where as I am trying to do is as below.

Scenario:
As shown in the mockup screenshot >> Cards will be displayed in the home screen >> users clicks on one of the Card >> background should be transparent 50% and movie details should get displayed in sliding button panel >> PLAY NOW should be active

Like the left menu loading in the given template below - playdo template

one of the similar example I found is this but as I mentioned this is hover feature - [Sliding bottom panel through HTML, CSS and JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798459/sliding-bottom-panel-through-html-css-and-js)

An other from the top sliding - http://hoveralls.design-way.ro/

Template in the screenshot that i am using is - https://github.com/tomclaus/playdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to the front-end world.

What you need to do is to create two different css classes that contain the things you want to change (in this case the top and the transparency). One for when your card/tile is "minimized" and one for when is "maximized".

```
.minimized{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
    top: 90%;
}

.maximized{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 1);
    top: 75%;
}
```

and then apply a click event to your card/title using jQuery or Javascript and swap those classes to give the proper behavior.

```
$("#card").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('minimized')){

        $(this).removeClass('minimized');
        $(this).addClass('maximized');
    }
    else{

        $(this).removeClass('maximized');
        $(this).addClass('minimized');
    }
});
```

Make sure that the CSS for your card/tile includes this:

```
-webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
```

That line will give a smooth transition when you swap the minimized and maximized classes.

Please check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMy97/3/) to see the code in action.

ps. Since I'm using the "-webkit-" prefix for the transition this example only will work with webkit browsers (safari and chrome)

Comment: Gary - your example looks good but the thing which I am trying to do is. I have cards in my home screen and when I click on one of them it's taking me to new page and I thinking to do instead of new page the sliding button up and display the card details in it by making home page as 50% transparent with gray color.

Mockup screen - 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6laW1_sl3NrSTyJIMkZrUTRtSlU/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: Ok I think I'm getting there however the link for the mockup screen is not working please fix it so I can understand better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: gotcha... I fixed it. Now you should be able to view the mockup screen. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6laW1_sl3NrSTJIMkZrUTRtSlU/edit

Comment: Thanks, Gary. Appreciate your replies.

Comment: Thanks for replies in Stackoverflow. I am planning to create a website in HTML5,JSON,Mongo DB and will you be interested in developing it and being the part of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally understood what you want to do with the mockup.
Well the idea is the same, and I'm sure it can be implemented in many other ways but I hope this one helps you to understand what is going on.

Pretty much you need two states (classes) for the actions you want to achieve.

A Minimized and Maximized for the div that holds the movie details.

```
#details{
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
    background-color: #2980b9;

    color: white;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;    
}

.minimized{
    top: 100%;
}

.maximized{
    top: 40%;
}
```

And other two for the "gray courtain" that sits on top of the cards when the details are show.

```
#courtain{
     position:absolute;
     background-color: rgba(100,100,100, 0.5);
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}

.active{
    z-index: 2;
}

.deactive{
    z-index: -1;
}
```

All these must be controlled or toggled using Javascript with a click event for the Card.

```
function hideAndShow(){
    var details = $('#details');
    var courtain = $('#courtain');

    if(details.hasClass('minimized')){
        courtain.removeClass('deactive');
        courtain.addClass('active');
        details.removeClass('minimized');
        details.addClass('maximized');
    }
    else{
        courtain.removeClass('active');
        courtain.addClass('deactive');
        details.removeClass('maximized');
        details.addClass('minimized');
    }
}
```

It is important to check the "z-index" values on the states to place them correctly above the other, the one with the highest z-index value is the one that remains on top.

I've updated the [JSFiddle, check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/sMy97/5/) and hopefully all this makes sence.